# How to change Flutter for web Font?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to change the font of the title in my Flutter for Web Application how can i do it? I found out that the pubsec.yaml is completely different than the mobile version here is the file:

```
name: projectbaseclient
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.5.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

This is the FontManifest.json:

```
[
    {
      "family": "Poppins",
      "fonts": [
        {
          "asset": "fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "KronaOne",
      "fonts": [
        {
          "asset": "fonts/KronaOne-Regular.ttf"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Ubuntu",
      "fonts": [
        {
          "asset": "fonts/Ubuntu-Regular.ttf"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I have already created a folder assets/fonts and added the fonts in the folder also i created the FontManifest.json and put it in the assets folder but it the code is not working it gives me error when i change the fontFamily parameter in the Text object.

how can i use the fonts to the Flutter for Web project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if `assets` folder is located in `web` folder. Next, compare `FontManifest.json` content with the example below:

```
[
  {
    "family": "Rubik",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf"
      },
      {
        "asset": "fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf",
        "weight": 500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**update**

Since the [Flutter for web](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web) project is currently merged with the main `Flutter` repository, this method is no longer recommended. Created in `web` folder `FontManifest.json` file conflicts with created by compiler one. Specify fonts in the in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: This is simliar of what i did, i have just uploaded the FontManifest.json, now the question is i have lots of Fonts of the same family but i dont want to use them all, do i have to declare them all in the FontManifest.json?

Comment: Declare only those that use.