# How to add custom font in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, custom-font, flutter-web

So I am developing flutter mobile apps for some time now, and I want to explore flutter web, now I tried to add custom font but it is not showing custom font.

I have added all the dependencies and made a separate folder for fonts and added into pubspec.yaml like how I do in flutter mobile.

My main.dart

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text("Dextroxd",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 36.0,
              fontFamily: 'CookieFam',
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
            )),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My pubspec

```
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0 <3.0.0'


flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: CookieFam
      fonts:
       - asset: assets/Cookie-Regular.ttf



dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.6.2
  build_web_compilers: ^2.1.0
  pedantic: ^1.7.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
```

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/docs/migration_guide.md#webassetsfontmanifestjson-optional

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Flutter for web Font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023412/how-to-change-flutter-for-web-font)

Comment: Not a duplicate, possibly Flutter does not currently support custom fonts (.ttf hosted) for Web.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add font in the font folder and also add in the pubspec.yaml for example refer given images

Font Folder:

[image]

pubspec.yaml

[image]

now for the web add the `assets` folder in the web section and add below JSON file with the name web/assets/`FontManifest.json`

[image]

```
[
  {
    "family": "MuliBold",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "fonts/Muli-Bold.tff"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "family": "MuliExtraBold",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "fonts/Muli-ExtraBold.ttf"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "family": "MuliRegular",
    "fonts": [
      {
        "asset": "fonts/Muli-Regular.ttf"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Great now your font applied to your flutter web application.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I had to add FontManifest to root directory assets, but this shouldn't be necessary. Seems like a Flutter bug.