# Font doesn't change (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

this is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: const Text(
              'you talk of the pain like it is all alright',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Arima',
                fontSize: 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

and this is the pubspec.yaml:

```
  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Arima
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Arima-Regular.ttf
  #      - asset: fonts/Arima-Italic.ttf

  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

I'm learning flutter and I don't know why font doesn't change even though I'm doing everything,I watched many videos on YouTube but it didn't work even though I did everything that was in the videos

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to put the ttf file under those font asset folder?

Comment: have you restarted the app

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: Check if font file exists. Don't forget to call `flutter pub get` after adding/replacing font. Restart app.

Comment: I tried everything they wrote and it didn't work I added a font folder and added the font and also tried 'flutter clean', also I opened the terminal and try flutter pub get but nothing happened

Comment: Ah, i didn't catch that you include flutter web tag, so I assume you run this for flutter web. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63813137/5262697)

Answer (score 1):

## Here are a couple things to check!

NOTE: Changes like adding a font/asset to the `pubspec.yaml` do not apply until with hot-reload/restart and require you to fully restart flutter.

### A: Files do not exist at location

Make sure that the font files do exist at `fonts/Arima-Regular.ttf`. The root directory is your project directory (the folder that contains `lib`, `pubspec.yaml`, etc.)

### B: Font files are invalid

Make sure the font files are valid! You can check this on a website like [FontDrop](https://fontdrop.info/).

### C: Pubspec.yaml is invalid

Run `flutter pub get` and make sure the `pubspec.yaml` file is valid.

### D: Web Only

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57344511/how-to-add-custom-font-in-flutter-web/63813137#63813137) for solution!

### E: Build Cache Needs Cleaning

Run `flutter clean` and restart the app.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it is very useful for a beginner like me, but after checking the things you wrote, I tried restarting the application and it didn't work.  and This comment was written in debug console 'Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13.' what should I do?

Comment: Do you mind sending the full log (via Pastebin) or another similar platform?

Answer (score 1):

I had problems because of wrong indentation in font part of pubspec file. Pay attention to spaces or the requested use of the font will be ignored without any error or warning by Flutter.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I don't even remember when I changed the code indentation in the "fonts" section of the pubspec file.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is Formatting .
Check :

```
# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/demo/
    - translations/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: Rubik
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Black.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/Rubik-SemiBold.ttf
          weight: 600


  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[image: This is Structure]

[image]