# FontWeight not working when using GoogleFonts

Tags: flutter, web

I am using Flutter Web (which is currently in beta) and it seems that the `FontWeight` of the `Text` Widget is not working properly while using *GoogleFonts*.
The problem does not exist when the default Font is used.

---

**Project:**

The project was created with the following commands

```
flutter channel beta 
flutter upgrade 
flutter config --enable-web
flutter create web_font_not_working
```

**Example Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
          textTheme: GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme()),
      home: HomePage(),    
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'This text should be bold',
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        Text('This text is normal'),
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

---

**Result of the Example Code:**

[image]

**Side effects:**

When saving the code, the browser refreshes as expected and shows a bold text for a short time. After the page is fully loaded the website looks as shown above.

**Question(s):**

1. Am i doing something wrong?
2. Is this a bug in the software?
3. Is the [GoogleFonts Package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts) not supporting web yet? If this is the case what is a
   suitable workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is now obsolete.

I am currently using `flutter 1.21.0-9.1.pre` and `google_fonts` is working as expected.

If you have a similar problem upgrade to the most recent flutter version.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see down below, google_fonts currently only supports ANDROID and IOS.

[image]

I think you might consider [filtering your search](https://pub.dev/flutter/packages?q=fonts&platform=web) when looking for a new plugin. This way, it will only show packages that support flutter web.

Also, you may want to take a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57023412/how-to-change-flutter-for-web-font) as it shows how to change fonts on flutter web

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I expected.. Often it seems that packages not explicitly supporting web are still working but i guess in this case its not the case. Furthermore it seems that the referenced Q & A is a bit outdated but I will try to work it out anyways.