# GoogleFont-Weight issue on copyWith

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, google-font-api

I'm creating a text-style model and using getter to have the text-Style that use [google_fonts](https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts). The issue occurs when I provide `fontWeight:` property. Also, the `fontWeight` is not providing similar look as GoogleFont.

I've tested on another project, rebuilding the project, using `html renderer`. I've checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62959810/10157127) but it is not working.

**Comparison between styles**

[image: comparison image]

> But [Looks from GoogleFont](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato?preview.text=weight&preview.text_type=custom)

[image]

**`flutter doctor -v`** no issue

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    10.0.19043.1288], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.5.2 at C:\Tools\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git        
    • Framework revision 3595343e20 (3 weeks ago), 2021-09-30 12:58:18  
      -0700
    • Engine revision 6ac856380f
    • Dart version 2.14.3
```

**Model class**

```dart
class AppTextStyles {
  static TextStyle get normalMidBlod => const TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 33,
      );

  static TextStyle get latoMidBlod => GoogleFonts.lato(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, //this one
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 33,
      );
  static TextStyle get lato => GoogleFonts.lato(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontSize: 33,
      );
}
```

**Test Widget**

```dart
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Column(
            children: const [
              Text("style: TextStyle.."),
              Text(
                "w100",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "w200",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "w300",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "w400",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                " w500",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                " w600",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w700",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w800",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800, fontSize: 33),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w900",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 33),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 30,
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("normalMidBlod.copyWith"),
              Text(
                "w100",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
              ),
              Text(
                "w200",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
              ),
              Text(
                "w300",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              ),
              Text(
                "w400",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
              Text(
                " w500",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              Text(
                " w600",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w700",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w800",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
              ),
              Text(
                "  w900",
                style: AppTextStyles.normalMidBlod
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 30,
          ),
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(text: "latoBold.copyWith \n"),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w100 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w200 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w300 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w400 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: " w500 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: " w600 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w700 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w800 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w900 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                      .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 30,
          ),
          RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(text: "lato.copyWith \n"),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w100 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w100),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w200 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w200),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w300 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "w400 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: " w500 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: " w600 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w700 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w800 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                ),
                TextSpan(
                  text: "  w900 \n",
                  style:
                      AppTextStyles.lato.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a bug on the google_fonts_flutter package repo that talks about this: https://github.com/material-foundation/google-fonts-flutter/issues/141

To summarize, when you create a Google Font TextStyle, the fontFamily is set to the original weight you specified (ex. 'poppins-w400') instead of the general fontFamily name ('poppins').

You can fix this by specifying the fontFamily in your copyWith method.

```
 TextSpan(
                  text: "  w900 \n",
                  style: AppTextStyles.latoMidBlod
                       .copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.poppins().fontFamily,
                     ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Only certain fonts support one ttf file with different weights. If you notice the alphabet g it looks different in each weight. You may have to download the full font family from Google fonts and include that in your pubspec.yaml under assets. It should work.

Check https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts bundling font in application assets section.

Comment: It works with some-weights, and yes there are missing `weight-font file` on lato. But the about the package README , they said `With the google_fonts package, .ttf or .otf files do not need to be stored in your assets folder and mapped in the pubspec...` and it is not working properly with api.

Comment: Yeah it works on almost 75% of the fonts. Some doesn't work as expected so they also suggest to bundle the fonts with the application. It's in the same link that I posted here. The last section in read me